# How do you handle environment specific javascript files in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, assets

Let's say you have different settings in development vs. production ( different options, different timings for `setInterval`/`setTimeout` ). How do you handle changes between configurations?

I was thinking of using a generator, and everytime I switch between environments, I could regenerate the relevant js files. What is your approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very, very simply. In my layout:

```
<% if Rails.env.development? %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "development.js" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Why do I always take the complicated path? ... but still, you'd have to keep 2 versions of the same source file under version control, right?

Comment: No, you'd have a `development.js` file which is conditionally included, and a normal `application.js` which is always included.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how many of these different settings you have, I would use the ENV['RAILS_ENV'] (Rails 2.3, it might have changed in Rails 3+) to see if you are in 'production', 'development', etc.

If it's just a stylesheet or javascript file I would have these checks in the application layout.  If your switches are more in depth, I would make a helper in the application helper which would tell you which environment your're code's currently in and just call that helper from your code.